# How to deal with autofilter using vba

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t9By.png)

I am having trouble with below line codes at line ActiveSheet.ShowAllData because at times my worksheet has the auto filter on and at times off. Is there a way to cater for this ??

[image]

Comment: See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub Framm()
    With ActiveSheet
        If (.AutoFilterMode And .FilterMode) Or .FilterMode Then
            .ShowAllData
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that this does not actually *remove* autofilters, only removes any *de-selections.*  It will also:

- not barf if all data is already showing
- not barf if filtering not is present.

Answer (score 0):

It's so much easier if you paste the code straight into your question rather than display a picture -  can't copy and paste a picture into the VBE.

You need to check if anything's filtered before clearing the filter:

```
If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
```

Comment: @Darren.Thank you lots...much appreciate your help